# How does Clairvoyance work?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

You can see as if you were elsewhere in your field of view.

It mentions that you can move the point.

> The subject can see distant scenes as if physically
> present at a chosen point within the sensory range of the
> spell. The visual point may be moved to any other point
> within range of the spell as a Complex Action

Can you jump to a point you NOW see, or must you remain within the original sight range of the caster?

Nothing speaks like an example like:
Can you look under a door, and project your sight on the other side so you can see, and THEN jump to the middle to have a better view, and THEN jump to look in the drawer that's been carelessly left open?

What are the limits on the spell?

Side Question: Do you need to spend the action to "turn around", or have you got a full 360*360 arc of movement for free (but you still need to turn, you couldn't possibly process all that information in a single go)?

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

That's exactly what the text is saying. You can move your point of view to a point that you cannot see yourself with a complex action as long as it's in the spell's range.

Your example is unclear as "project" is normally meant to be short for *astral projection* and I'm not sure how that would interfere. What you can do for example is cast the spell, move the point to the next corner, turn and move again so that you now can see from a point around the corner that you yourself cannot see.

Comment: I corrected my exemple, as i meant "project your sight" as in, "move your new point of vision".
Out of curiosity, got any RAW on that?
I'm using it this way because, otherwise the spell is just borderline useful, but i'd really like to know the idea behind it.

Comment: You quoted the RAW. It's right there. *may be moved to **any** other point within range*

Comment: hahaha, i forgot i mentionned that.  I must be sleepier than i think. Really, i meant RAW on the limits of the spell... like can you "sight-jump" all your way to new mexico in 10-20 ish kilometers jumps? or to the moon, since you clearly see the sky so you can jump to space and then to the moon, or japan or wherever else? (thanks for keeping me on tracks, btw) (for the records, it would take around 15 minutes to jump from seattle to disneyland in 20 KM jumps, and about 6 seconds to jump to the moon, that sounds a little powerful)

Comment: @Mouhgouda You don't need any more info for this to be RAW.  nvoigt's is sufficiently clear.  If you are still unsure, ask another question about how to support something with RAW in Shadowrun.  Also note the bit about the spell's range.

Comment: the range is T... for touch... which is problematic.

Comment: That just means you must touch the chosen creature or subject that you wish to grant clairvoyance (in case you don't want to cast the spell on yourself). The actual range for the sensor is detailed at the beginning of the Detection spell section: "The standard range of the sense a Detection spell grants is the spell’s Force x caster’s Magic in meters as a radius from the target of the spell. Extended-range detection spells have a Force x Magic x 10 meter range." Therefore casting a Force 6 clairvoyance spell on yourself with Magic 6 will allow you to see everything within a 36 meter radius.